# iptables Port redirect does not work on debian buster

Tags: debian, iptables, debian-buster

I have a setup with `iptables` this I use already on many previous versions of debian before, now with debian buster it does not work.

I want to route all traffic from `tun0` (openvpn) via `iptables` to a specific port, here is my `rules.v4`:

```
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:MY_REJECT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -i ens32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j MY_REJECT

-A FORWARD -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j MY_REJECT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A MY_REJECT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A MY_REJECT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A MY_REJECT -p icmp -j DROP
-A MY_REJECT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040

-A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.0/24 -o ens32 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

the same setup on previous debian is working without problems, 
thank you

the output of `iptables -t nat -nvL`:

```
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  tun0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp redir ports 9040

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 60 packets, 4280 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ens32   10.1.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
```

[edit: 8. June]
I did some changes, please see the update in the 'iptables -t nat - L -vn' it is definitly the REDIRECT that does not work I test all incomming traffic, I can see all traffic comming to tun0 but not redirect to port 9040

Comment: Do you see the incoming traffic with `tcpdump -i tun0 -n`? Add the output of `iptables -t nat -nvL` to your question.

Comment: yes, I can see the incomming traffic on tun0

Comment: It seems the packet filter doesn't get to see the packets. Add the output of `sysctl -a | grep -E '(all|tun).*\.rp_filter'` to your question. Execute `ip route get $IP` for one of the source addresses you see in `tcpdump`.